# What colors to use for accessibility?

Tags: colors, accessibility

I'm designing a logo for web and software (also reporting) entity. What I want is to make the logo the most accessible posible with colors, trying to choose the best color for normal and colorblind people.

I tried to find some standardization color accessibility but I found nothing. Are there some tips or standards for this? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting from scratch, the main goal is a contrast ratio that suits the needs of the font size and weight. Larger and bolder fonts need a much lower contrast ratio. This is very important for logos and any image that includes text, as the browser zoom tool won't necessarily enlarge images enough to make the text more distinct.

Also, you're better off making the contrast higher than the minimum ratios. I'll typically start with the colors I want to use in the design, implement and then test the colors with a tool like the color contrast analyzer Chrome extension. I'll then make small changes to get a good contrast and still the colors I want to use. Webaim.org has a lot of information and [good analysis tool](http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/). Also, I recommend reading the [W3C recommendations](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html).

Comment: The answer is extremely generic; not very actionable.  However, there is a lot of good detail in your links.  If the links break, the answer wouldn't be very useful.  Can you expand your answer to include some of the essential details from the links (use use the links for attribution and further reading)?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I want to show you an extension which help coloblind people to see normal colors. http://colorblind.tech/ this is the site of the extension and this is direct link for the extension : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/colorblind-dalton/afcafnelafcgjinkaeohkalmfececool Proven work